# What are the standard headers in NNTP?

Tags: protocols, nntp

After looking at the [NNTP standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), I have figured out how to extract a header from the message, how to fold headers, and how to separate the header label from the header text.  What I can't find is an official list of standard NNTP headers.  The standard lists `Subject, From, Date, Message-id, Reference` but not `Groups` which I know needs to be there.

Is there an official list of all the official NNTP headers?  For bonus marks, is there a list of commonly-used, unofficial headers?

**EDIT**

I found the [list of standard headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1036).  Is there a similar list of non-standard, but common, headers?

Comment: Although I am using Java, the protocol standard is completely language-agnostic.

Comment: I'd be glad to share notes.  if you just want an Enumeration of Header's, that's easy [enough](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/javadoc/gnu/mail/providers/nntp/NNTPMessage.html#getAllHeaders%28%29).  Are you after the headers for a specific article?  All articles in a newsgroup?  Just asking in general?  If only for my edification, I'd be interested in some code and seeing what you're specifically after.

Comment: I think you're after this:  Newsgroups: gwene.com.economist     however, be aware that it can be Newsgroups: gwene.com.economist,groupx,group_y,etc,etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not looking at the correct RFC the one you link to is the general message format.

Netnews is explicitly addressed in the [Netnews Article Format RFC 5536](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5536) which lists the headers (with the page numbers of the RFC where they are defined) as

```
      3.1. Mandatory Header Fields ...................................10
           3.1.1. Date ...............................................11
           3.1.2. From ...............................................11
           3.1.3. Message-ID .........................................11
           3.1.4. Newsgroups .........................................13
           3.1.5. Path ...............................................14
           3.1.6. Subject ............................................16
      3.2. Optional Header Fields ....................................16
           3.2.1. Approved ...........................................17
           3.2.2. Archive ............................................17
           3.2.3. Control ............................................17
           3.2.4. Distribution .......................................18
           3.2.5. Expires ............................................19
           3.2.6. Followup-To ........................................19
           3.2.7. Injection-Date .....................................20
           3.2.8. Injection-Info .....................................20
           3.2.9. Organization .......................................22
           3.2.10. References ........................................22
           3.2.11. Summary ...........................................23
           3.2.12. Supersedes ........................................23
           3.2.13. User-Agent ........................................23
           3.2.14. Xref ..............................................24
      3.3. Obsolete Header Fields ....................................25
           3.3.1. Lines ..............................................25
```