# Which headers do I have to supply to NNTP?

Tags: protocols, nntp

This is related to [a previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895531/what-are-the-standard-headers-in-nntp). Section 1.5 of RFC 5536 mentions that submitted proto-articles may lack some of the mandatory headers that full articles have. Servers will always pass full articles to clients or peers, so they’ll fill in missing headers. But what are the optional headers?

Both RFC 5536 and 3977 mention filling in the Message-ID if needed, but not anything else. The examples in 3977 (section 6.3.1.3) imply only From, Newsgroups, and Subject are needed; servers can fill in Message-ID, Date, and Path. That makes sense; is that the actual list?  Is there some official list somewhere, maybe in an obsolete RFC?

Comment: Poking around while reading @AlekseyTsalolikhin answer, I ran across RFC 5537, where Section 3.4.1 confirms my supposition.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

The precursors to RFC 5536 are:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1036
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc850

RFC 1036 is listed in RFC 5536 (RFC 5536 obsoletes RFC 1036).

RFC 1036 says:

The required header lines are "From", "Date", "Newsgroups", "Subject", "Message-ID", and "Path".

Update: see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5537 (thanks CTMacUser) which says,

```
any of the following mandatory header fields MAY be omitted:
   Message-ID, Date, and Path.
```

Comment: Posts through the Netnews system must be complete, but some of those required headers can be left out by the poster and filled in by the first server. See my comment on the original post for more.